# Windows event log Logstash and Elasticsearch filter doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to filter "New Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" in logstash.

Here the Windows Event log, created by ossec agent

```
** Alert 1460299512.116024: - windows,authentication_success,
2016 Apr 10 16:45:12 (windows10) 192.168.0.17->WinEvtLog
Rule: 18107 (level 3) -> 'Process Creation.'
User: (no user)
2016 Apr 10 07:45:09 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_SUCCESS(4688): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: (no user): no domain: DESKTOP-2D562R2: A new process has been created. Subject:  Security ID:  S-1-5-21-3956991881-1104172218-599705502-1001  Account Name:  Localroot  Account Domain:  DESKTOP-2D562R2  Logon ID:  0x27c1e  Process Information:  New Process ID:  0x12a8  New Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe  Token Elevation Type: %%1938  Creator Process ID: 0x1a0`enter code here`
```

I use this filter in logstash

```
root@ubuntulogstash:/etc/logstash/conf.d# cat all.conf
input {
# stdin{}
  udp {
     port => 9000
     type => "syslog"
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_host} %{DATA:syslog_program}: Alert Level: %{BASE10NUM:Alert_Level}; Rule: %{BASE10NUM:Rule} - %{GREEDYDATA:Description}; Location: %{GREEDYDATA:Details}" }
      add_field => [ "ossec_server", "%{host}" ]
}
   }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "syslog_hostname", "syslog_message", "syslog_pid", "message", "@version", "type", "host" ]
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["192.168.0.30:9200"]
        index => "ossec"
#       protocol => http
                }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: What does this configuration not do that you would like it to?

Comment: In elasticsearch it comes like this,
"Description": "Process Creation.",
"Details": "(windows10) 192.168.0.17->WinEvtLog; 2016 Apr 10 03:13:44 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_SUCCESS(4688): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: (no user): no domain: DESKTOP-2D562R2: A new process has been created. Subject: Security ID: S-1-5-18 Account Name: DESKTOP-2D562R2$ Account Domain: WORKGROUP Logon ID: 0x3e7 Process Information: New Process ID: 0x1798 New Process Name: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe Token Elevation Type: %%1938 Creator Process ID: 0x2b8 ",

Comment: I want to separate New Procces Name,

Comment: Your grok pattern includes a reference to "Alert level" which doesn't appear in the sample input string you've provided.  As such, the grok would fail and the other fields would not be created.  Please provide an example where things match.

Comment: @Alain Collins 
Thanks, but were I put is code "New Process Name: %{NOTSPACE:processName}%SPACE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
New Process Name: %{NOTSPACE:processName}%SPACE
```

would work in a grok pattern